# how to select the clicked input in css

Tags: html, css, width, selector, underline

```css
#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(1):focus ~ #underline1,#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(2):focus  ~ #underline2,#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(3):focus  ~ #underline3,#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(4):focus  ~ #underline4,#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(5):focus  ~ #underline5,#registeration_form input:nth-of-type(6):focus  ~ #underline6{
    transition: 1000ms;
    width: 100%;
}
```

is there any simple way to write this code ?

Comment: Do you have a minimum html snippet to work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're building, but here's a guess (based on naming) that would really simplify your `CSS`. Basically, I change things to depend on shared classes, not specific `id`s.

```css
.field .underline {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 100ms;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

#registeration_form input:focus + .underline {
 width: 100%; 
}

.field {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.field input {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="registeration_form">
  <div class="field">
    <input placeholder="Enter Name" aria-label="enter name" type="text" class="input" id="name" name="name">
    <span role="presentation" class="underline"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input placeholder="Enter Username" aria-label="enter username" type="text" class="input" id="username" name="username">
    <span role="presentation" class="underline"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input placeholder="Enter Email" aria-label="enter email" type="text" class="input" id="email" name="email">
    <span role="presentation" class="underline"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0nkw2sy/12/)

Comment: thanks the problem was with the selector instead of + i used ~ thanks again